# Sentence segmentation with trailing whitespaces in stanza (stanford corenlp)

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Using the library Stanza for sentence segmentation :

```py
import stanza
stanza.download('en')
snlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang="en",processors='tokenize')
doc = snlp(text)
doc_sents = [sentence.text for sentence in doc.sentences]
```

Output:

```py
["Arthur's Magazine (1844–1846) was an American literary periodical published in Philadelphia in the 19th century.",
 'Edited by T.S. Arthur, it featured work by Edgar A. Poe, J.H. Ingraham, Sarah Josepha Hale, Thomas G. Spear, and others.',
 'In May 1846 it was merged into "Godey\'s Lady\'s Book".',
 "First for Women is a woman's magazine published by Bauer Media Group in the USA.",
 'The magazine was started in 1989.',
 'It is based in Englewood Cliffs, New Jersey.',
 'In 2011 the circulation of the magazine was 1,310,696 copies.']
```

But, Then I'm losing the trailing whitespace, is there a way to "keep" them, similar to the behavior in spacy using
`[sent.text_with_ws for sent in doc.sents]`
Any workaround will help as well. I need to keep the original whitespaces to handle indexes that written originally on the full text

```py
["Arthur's Magazine (1844–1846) was an American literary periodical published in Philadelphia in the 19th century. ",
 'Edited by T.S. Arthur, it featured work by Edgar A. Poe, J.H. Ingraham, Sarah Josepha Hale, Thomas G. Spear, and others. ',
 'In May 1846 it was merged into "Godey\'s Lady\'s Book". ',
 "First for Women is a woman's magazine published by Bauer Media Group in the USA. ",
 'The magazine was started in 1989. ',
 'It is based in Englewood Cliffs, New Jersey. ',
 'In 2011 the circulation of the magazine was 1,310,696 copies.']
```

Comment: If stanza isn't mandatory you can use `nltk` which does span tokenization (it returns indexes instead of a new string) [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html?highlight=punkt#nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer.span_tokenize) for punkt sentence tokenizer.

Comment: In stanza the original text is available via `.text` and the `misc` attribute of tokens displays the beginning and end of the tokens.

Comment: @ygorg the last token of each sentence is the '.' and do not includes the white space in the misc

Comment: Yes but based on the end of the last token and the length of `doc.text`, the difference would be the whitespace ?